# Как сделать чтобы рандомайзер бесконечно генерировал цифры

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Я написал простенький рандомайзер, но после генерирования числа программа завершается. Мне нужно чтобы рандомайзер выдавал новое число на нажатие кнопки enter (тоесть пустую строку - ""). У меня получилось сделать это с помощью **return**, но в таком случае программа просит заново ввести числа. Заранее спасибо.

```
print("Добро пожаловать в randomizer! Выберите опцию:")
print("1 - Случайное число")

num = input()

def random_number():
    first_num = int(input("Введите первое число:"))
    second_num = int(input("Введите второе число:"))
    gennum = random.randint(first_num,second_num)
    print("Число: " + str(gennum))
    

if num == "1":
    random_number() 
else:
    print("Ошибка")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from random import randint

lower = int(input("Введите первое число: "))
upper = int(input("Введите второе число: "))

while not input('Для продолжения нажмите Enter: '):
    print(randint(lower, upper))
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
# pip install keyboard
import random, time, keyboard


if __name__ == '__main__':
    alive = True

    def foo():
        global alive
        alive = False

    keyboard.add_hotkey('esc', foo)

    while alive:
        first_num = int(input("Введите первое число:"))
        second_num = int(input("Введите второе число:"))
        gennum = random.randint(first_num, second_num)
        print("Число: " + str(gennum) + "\nНажмите esc для выхода.")
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: `pip install keyboard`